Multiple 2 wire smokes that are wired as home runs
I have a vista panel and 5x System Sensor 2WTA-B 2-Wire. Each smoke has their own 2 wire cable that run back to the panel like a home run. The cable only has two wires and I planed to connect them to a cosmod2w but I obviously didn’t wire the smokes in parallel. The drywall is already installed and can’t fix this. What can I do to wire these smokes together in a way that if one detects smokes then they all sound?

Smoke detectors

Touché probably not unless the whole conversation is centered on a certain type of apple and then I say I have a red

Can you provide links to the installation documents?

Oh dear, you're going to have to rewire the whole. entire. lot.
Whoever wired your smoke detectors was clearly not versed in fire alarm wiring, because the home run scheme they used for the wiring is not supervisable for wiring faults at all.  This is a severe violation of NFPA 72 29.10.6.7 and would get a fire alarm inspector to red-tag your system were they to look at it.
As a result of this, you'll have to convert it to a supervised daisy-chain circuit with an end-of-line resistor so that your panel can tell you that some rodent chewed up your fire alarm wiring, instead of finding out the hard way when your house is on fire despite the alarms being silent.

upvote for understanding what the OP was talking about.

Damn I had a feeling but wanted to confirm. I saw this https://www.reddit.com/r/audiophile/s/bGao7qTfmm and was wondering if something like this might work but then i don’t know where I would put an EOLR

@jay613 -- there is a heartbeat function of sorts on the COSMODs, but it doesn't count as a SLC for detector wiring, so you aren't allowed to T-tap

Thsnks ThreePhaseEel.   Strange, my comment to which you replied is gone.  I didn't delete it.
